# Adding class based on url and removing on mouseover

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Basically just adding a class to a subNav menu if the user is on that page. When they hover over the menu, the selected class goes away. But if they mouseout from the menu, I need the selected class to reappear. There must be a more efficient way of doing this...

Sorry I didn't include the html. You can see it here in action: http://oursaviorschurch.com/GivingNew. I'm developing with asp.net.

```
$(function () {
    var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
    if (/GivingNew/.test(loc)) {
        $('.SideGrace').addClass('selected');
    };
    if (/Options/.test(loc)) {
        $('.SideOptions').addClass('selected');
    };
    if (/FAQ/.test(loc)) {
        $('.SideFAQ').addClass('selected');
    };
    if (/GiveNow/.test(loc)) {
        $('.SideGive').addClass('selected');
    };
    $('.sideNav').mouseover(function () {
        $('.sideNav li a').removeClass('selected');
    });
    $('.sideNav').mouseout(function () {
        var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
        if (/GivingNew/.test(loc)) {
            $('.SideGrace').addClass('selected');
        };
        if (/Options/.test(loc)) {
            $('.SideOptions').addClass('selected');
        };
        if (/FAQ/.test(loc)) {
            $('.SideFAQ').addClass('selected');
        };
        if (/GiveNow/.test(loc)) {
            $('.SideGive').addClass('selected');
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: And your HTML would be..? Also what's the relationship between the RegExp string you're testing for and the `a` element you're testing?

Comment: you can see it happening here: http://oursaviorschurch.com/GivingNew. It's the right menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

According to you, do you want the following...

> When they hover over the menu, the selected class goes away. But if
>   they mouseout from the menu, I need the selected class to reappear.

**Why not when user focus the menu you add `selected` and on focusout remove it ?**
You can do it this way:
Check [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

```
$(function () {

    $('.sideNav').on('mouseout mouseover', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

});
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/C9nrg/)**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming mark-up similar to the following:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="menuLinks" href="http://example.com/home/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuLinks" href="http://example.com/about/">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuLinks" href="http://example.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuLinks" href="http://example.com/options/">Options</a></li>
</ul>​
```

Note that I'm using a particular `class` on the `a` elements to specify those that I wish to search through, and *also* I'm using the text of the `a` elements to search through the `window.location` string, this may require adjustment based on your own mark-up and logic.

The following jQuery works, under those assumptions:

```
var loc = 'http://www.example.com/options/';

$('a.menuLinks').each(

function() {
    var needle = $(this).text().toLowerCase().split(/ /)[0];
    if (loc.indexOf(needle) > -1) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).attr('data-selected',true);
    }
}).closest('ul').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $(this).find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    } else if (e.type == 'mouseleave') {
        $(this).find('a[data-selected]').addClass('selected');
    }
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DTGUN/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [has-attribute-selector `[attribute]`](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- JavaScript:

  - [`e.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.type).
  - [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
  - [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
  - [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).

Comment: This looks awesome, though I don't understand it (jQuery novice here). I'll test it out when I get to the office tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, what I would do is add the "selected" tag to the current page with PHP and to just the stylings/effects with jQuery and CSS.

I'm imagining something like when you hover over a link of the page you're currently in, you'll show something like "You're already here!". In this case, working with PHP to printout the 'selected' class, seems to be more logical, and to do the rest will be easy.

Also, since you're always testing against your 'loc' var "test(loc)", instead of using multiple if's, you could use a 'switch'.